# VBA kill crashes after being called by auto_open

Tags: vba, excel, delete-file

I'm experiencing some trouble with my VBA code. I have created an application in Excel and its copies have been distributed to users. To be able to correct bugs or add some new functions, every copy stores information what version it is. I have written procedure, that opens (read-only) a central file, that is providing some data a and information, which version is current. If the file, that opened this central file is older, it gets updated.

So the auto_open calls a procedure discovers that it has to be updated, saves the current file AS FileName_old.xlsm (to have some backup), kills the FileName.xlsm and copies a new file from a template. The problem is that the procedure crashes when it tries to kill the old file (to be more precise, it just ends without any error message). What confuses me is that when I run the auto_open macro manually (F5), everything goes correctly. Even step by step goes right. Also, when I call the update process via a button in a worksheet, it works perfectly. Any idea, what might cause this problem?
Thanks

```
Sub auto_open()
    If Range("H_User").Value = "" Then UserNameWindows 'Write a user that is using this workbook in the range H_User

    If Range("H_Updated").Value < FileDateTime(Range("H_File_Data").Value) Then UpdateData
End Sub


Sub UpdateData()
    Dim ActWB As String
    ActWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    If Not FileExists(Range("H_File_Data").Value) Then
        MsgBox "The data file is not available!", vbCritical
        Workbooks(ActWB).Activate
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim WB As String, oknoData As String, IsTeam As Boolean, User As String
    Dim version As Integer, Subversion As Integer, DataPath As String

    On Error GoTo konec

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    IsTeam = False
    User = Range("H_User").Value
    WB = ActiveWindow.Caption
    version = Range("H_version").Value
    Subversion = Range("H_Subversion").Value
    Range("C_Data_All").ClearContents
    DataPath = Range("H_File_Data").Value
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=DataPath, ReadOnly:=True
    oknoData = ActiveWindow.Caption

    If Range("H_version_Spec").Value <= version Or (Range("H_version_Spec").Value = version And Range("H_Subversion_Spec").Value <= Subversion) Then
        FileUpdate
    End If

    'If there is no need to update the file then continue with in this procedure
End Sub

Sub FileUpdate()
    Dim NewPath As String, NewWB As String, OldPath As String, OldWB As String, BackupWB As String, BackupPath As String
    Dim MainWB As String, version As String, Subversion As String
    Dim versionMax As Integer, SubversionMax As Integer, versionMin As Integer, SubversionMin As Integer

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    version = Range("H_version").Value
    Subversion = Range("H_Subversion").Value

    OldPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    OldWB = ThisWorkbook.Name
    BackupWB = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 5) & "_old.xlsm"
    BackupPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & BackupWB

    If Not FileExists(Workbooks(OldWB).Names("H_File_Data").RefersToRange.Value) Then
        MsgBox "The data file is not available!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Workbooks.Open fileName:=Workbooks(OldWB).Names("H_File_Data").RefersToRange.Value, ReadOnly:=True
    MainWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    If version = Range("O_Spec_version").Value And Subversion >= Range("O_Spec_Subversion").Value Then
        'Just some little piece of code if the version is not lower
    Else
        If FileExists(BackupPath) Then Kill (BackupPath)
    If Not FileExists(Range("H_Path_Spec_Actual").Value) Then
        MsgBox "The spec template is not available!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs BackupPath
    Kill (OldPath)

    'Continue with update
    End If
End Sub

Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    FileExists= fso.FileExists(FilePath)
End Function
```

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with; it makes it far simpler to try and help you fix it...

Comment: Added the specific part. The Kill(OldPath) causes the problem. But again, only when the auto_open starts by itself, not when I run it manually

Comment: So you're killing the worksheet that's running the code... and are surprised when the code stops executing?

Comment: The worksheet that is running the code is the one that is now named Filename_old.xlsm. I'm killing the worksheet in the original location. If I was killing the worksheet that is running the code, the code wouldn't run even if started manually and I wouldn't be asking here

Comment: @ThomasInzina Certainly not, I'm not testing it in a public location.

Comment: Are you saying that any code after `Kill (OldPath)` does not execute?

Comment: @aphoria Exactly, but as mentioned before just when it starts by itself

Comment: Using your code above, I couldn't replicate the problem...it worked for me, even if I added code after the `Kill (OldPath)` line. Do you have any error handling wrapped around this code?

Comment: So I added the code. Hope that helps.

Comment: remove the `kill (old_path)` line. Or, you can try with a doevents, so that the `saveas` is finished, or put the `kill` after `'continue with update`.

Comment: Tried the DoEvents, but it didn't work either. The problem is that I have to kill the oldPath File, because a template with user data will take its place in the `'continue with update` part of code. I also tried to remove the `kill (oldPath)` method and force a saveas over this existing file. That also didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim BackupPath As String
    Dim OldPath As String

    BackupPath = "folder\Filename_old.xlsm"

    With ThisWorkbook
        OldPath = .FullName
        .SaveCopyAs BackupPath
        .Saved = True
        .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        Kill .FullName
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem with your code is, that it kills the workbook that is running the code, but I need the code to do some other stuff after that.

Comment: Could you do stuff _before_ killing the workbook? That would be the ideal.